# ¿Como configuar permisos de pull request?

Tags: github

He creado una organización en **Github** en la cual cree equipos, unos de lectura(**Read**). otros de escritura(**Write**) y un equipo tiene permisos **Triage**, que en teoria son para la gestión de los **pull request**.

Lo que quiero es que los de **Write** puedan subir sus **pull request** pero que ellos no puedan hacer **merge**.

Solo algunos usuarios son los que deben poder confirmar los **merge**

He revisado la configuración dentro de **Github** y he revisado un poco esta [documentación](https://docs.github.com/en/organizations/managing-organization-settings/disabling-or-limiting-github-actions-for-your-organization#enabling-workflows-for-private-repository-forks) al respecto pero no me queda claro como poder hacer eso o si es posible.